# How to connect MS Exchange to SQL Server through SSMS?

Tags: sql, powerbi, ssms, exchange-server

I know that in Power BI I can have access to a table having all my email properties (body, sender, subject etc) connecting to Microsoft Exchange.
I want to know if it is possible to have access to the same Exchange base through SSMS in a new table and how to do it.
Sorry if it is a basic question, I'm new in this area. Thanks!

Comment: SSMS is a client-tool specifically for Administering SQL Server.  I've been using it for over 20 years, but AFAIK, it will not connect to anything other than a SQL Server Instance.   There might be drivers or options that allow you to connect a SQL Server instance itself to Exchange or possibly through *SSIS* which is the BI tool for SQL Server.

Comment: Power BI can connect to them both.  Does that answer your question or are you asking how to do it *without* Power BI?

Comment: I can connect through Power BI and get the data I need, but the refresh is too slow (more than 40 minutes) even if I dont have many Power Query transformations. So I would try to have the data stored in SQL Server and maybe it would refresh faster. But thanks for the reply!

Comment: The few things I found on the internet about the subject refer to SSIS, but Im not familiar to it. I'm gonna look for more information about it

Comment: I think you can take advantage of SSIS as SSIS has a Power Quey Source. You can run the same M code inside SSIS's Power Query, create an ETL job and store the results in a SQL DB. Once the tables are created in sql, you can run sql queries on those.

Comment: Thank you, maybe thats the solution Im gonna adopt. BTW do you know if I can do what I want using Azure? I know nothing about it, but I know it's an alternative to SSMS, so...

Comment: I've use this a while ago, it uses an odbc connection https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/exchange-odbc-linked-server.rst